# Proving the uniform continuity of a function over the union of two overlapping intervals given its uniform continuity over each.

Tags: real-analysis

[image: From introduction to real analysis Bartle p. 144]

Please could someone help explain to me the choice of delta here. I am unsure how the definition of uniform continuity is being applied. I guess it is something to do with when x and u fall in different intervals J or I? Thanks for your help!

Comment: By choosing $\delta(\varepsilon)$ as above it can always be ensured that both $x$ and $y$ belong either to $I$ or $J$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you

Comment: @KarthikKannan I think you should edit your comment as an answer.